# Counting number of subsets which contain a specific element

Tags: discrete-mathematics

There is a set $x = \{A,B,C,D,E,F,G\}$ and the question ask for counting the number of subsets which contain $D$. And the answer is $2^6$. why would it be $2^6$? I know the total number of subsets is $2^{|x|}$ is it realated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Every set $X$ that contains $D$ can be written as $X = \{D\}\cup (X\setminus \{D\})$. Then $X\setminus \{D\}$ can be any subset of $\{A,B,C,E,F,G\}$. There are $2^6$ subsets there.